# Access parent control from iframe's codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, code-behind

So I'm pretty new to non-mvc web development, and I'm having an issue with iFrames.

In my main page, I have a checkbox which shows and hides an iframe via jQuery. In my iFrame's codebehind, I have a method `loadStuff()` which I only want to run if the iFrame is visible. That is, I don't want to just stick it in `page_load` because if I do, it's going to try and run every time the main page gets refreshed.

So I was thinking I'd just do a check to see if the checkbox in the main window is checked and if so, run the `loadStuff()` method.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to access that checkbox from the iFrame's codebehind. It seems like some variant of `this.Parent.FindControls()` would work, but I haven't had any luck with that.

Here's a little bit of what I have:

Main page (lets call it mainpage.aspx):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="showIFrame" onclick="if(this.Clicked) $('#iframe').show(); else $('#iframe').hide();" />

//...

<div id="iframe" style="display:none;">
<iframe runat="server" id="iframeNetSheet" .../></iframe>
</div>
```

So when that checkbox gets clicked, the iFrame gets shown. That's when I want to invoke the loading function. As of now, it's in the iFrame's page_load, which gets hit every time the parent page is loaded.

Can anyone get me pointed in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused... when you say about accessing a checkbox from the iFrame's codebehind, are you talking about being able to see controls on the parent page from the server when requesting an iFrame page?  Is this not something that you should be controlling from the jQuery in the parent page, as to what is requested as part of the iFrame?  I apologise if I have the wrong end of the stick.  (EDIT: what I mean is if you set the iFrame `src` to "about:blank" to start, and then only set the correct `src` when you make the iFrame visible)

Comment: @freefaller Not sure what you mean by "as to what is requested as part of the iFrame". I guess what I *should* be doing is loading the iFrame only when the checkbox gets checked, but frankly I'm not sure how to do that either. I'll edit the question to make this a little more clear.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you wouldn't think English is my first language!! What I'm getting at is that you do not (as standard) get any information about the parent page being passed into the iFrame, unless you start passing stuff via the query string, or submitting a form with the iFrame as the target. I still think you should be looking at only setting the `src` attribute of the iFrame when you make the iFrame visible

Comment: @freefaller is this even the way you'd do this, though? I feel as if there's a way easier way to do it. Check my edit, by the way

Comment: When the page is reloaded, are you wanting the checkbox to be in the same state?  (I.e. if checked, still checked on post-back and therefore iFrame is visible?)

Comment: @freefaller nah, the page shouldn't be reloaded after the checkbox is checked anyway. Hard to explain, really. The page gets reloaded a few times *before* the checkbox is even visible, and it's calling my `loadstuff()` function too early. But I think I'm going to go with @magnus 's suggestion to set the src attribute on the checkbox checked event

Comment: I'm writing an answer at the moment - just bugfixing

Comment: Looks like Magnus has got it covered... my fault for not being 100% confident with jQuery and taking too long to write/debug it!  Oh well, hope you get it sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `IFrame` on a page and that page is refreshed the iFrame is also going to be refreshed (every time). So I don't see any reason to check the parent page checkbox value. 
Also rather than just setting the visibility of the iframe (if set to visible and `src` url is blank) set the `src` and the frame will only be loaded (and `loadStuff()` called) when the checkbox is checked. 
The code would look something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="showIFrame" onclick="SetFrame(this.checked);" />

function SetFrame(isChecked)
{
   if(isChecked) 
   {
      $('#iframe').show(); 
      var iframeNetSheet = $('#iframeNetSheet');

      if(iframeNetSheet.attr("src") == "")
         iframeNetSheet.attr("src", "SomeUrl"); //This will invoke page_load on iframe.
   }
   else 
      $('#iframe').hide();
}
```

Leave `src` url of the frame blank by default in code. (only let it be set by script)

Comment: only thing that isn't worked is the `this.Clicked` that it's passing to the function is evaluating false. Any idea why? Maybe I need a `return true;` in the onclick to keep the default behavior?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt use `this.checked` instead

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. It's coming up undefined.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt That should work but you could try the jQuery version: `SetFrame($(this).is(':checked'));`

Comment: This is what I ended up using. Muchos gracias

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you have your iFrame `src` set to "about:blank" to start with - then when you click the checkbox you set the correct source.  Something like this...

```
<script type="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showIFrame").click(function() {
      var frame = $("#iframeNetSheet");
      if ($("#showIFrame").prop("checked")) {
        frame.show();
        if (frame.prop("src") == "about:blank") {
          frame.attr("src", "newpage.aspx");
        }
      } else {
        frame.hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="showIFrame" />
<iframe runat="server" id="iframeNetSheet" style="display:none;"/></iframe>
```

[Live JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tyDxa/2/)

(And after doing all that, because I'm not 100% confident on jQuery - I realise it's pretty much exactly what Magnus was saying from the start as well)

**Edit:** as Marcus kindly pointed out, there was no need to reset the `src` back to "about:blank", so have updated the code accordingly (and made slightly more efficient).

Comment: It seems unnecessary the set the `src` to blank when the frame is hidden. It only means that it needs to load the same url again if set to visible.

Comment: Yes, you are completely correct @Magnus... trying too hard and typing too quickly... I will alter accordingly (although it will start to look too much like your answer to be one in it's own right)